# Possible to create widget instance programatically?

Tags: magento, widget

I have a magento extension that is widget driven.  When the extension is installed, I want to create a default widget instance automatically for a user rather than have them go to CMS > Widget.

Is this possible?

Comment: For sure is possible. I don't know by heart how to to do it, but here is how you can find out. Try to manually create the widget in the admin then put `print_r($widgetInstance);exit` in `Mage_Widget_Adminhtml_Widget_InstanceController::saveAction()` to see how your the widget instance looks like. Then try to replicate it through your code. Again the `Mage_Widget_Adminhtml_Widget_InstanceController` can be a source of inspiration. This is how I usually create any entity instance in Magento.

Comment: you will need to look also in the table `widget_instance_page_layout` and `core_layout_update`